# Azure AD B2C: AADSTS70000: Authentication failed: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

trying to grab the token for the authorization_token that is returned to my OAuthCallback endpoint for my chat bot, using Postman chrome extension to test out the call:

```
POST /baad.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 06d9d95a-4e53-0333-5f51-ede4ae354443
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=[snipped clientid]&scope=openid+offline_access&code=[snipped code]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3978%2Fapi%2FOAuthCallback&p=b2c_1_sign-in
```

I get the [snipped code] by calling the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/baad.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?` after I login and the debug breakpoint stops at the `http://localhost:3987/api/OAuthCallback` on my localhost and I copy the code parameter value that is returned to the callback.

I've triple checked that redirect_uri and everything else is consistent. However, when I copy paste the code that is returned to my `http://localhost:3987/api/OAuthCallback` endpoint, it throws `AADSTS70000: Authentication failed: Authorization Code is malformed or invalid`

I don't understand what could be going wrong as I'm using the authorization code returned to my `/OAuthCallback` and puzzled as to why it will not work

Reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code/

Comment: Please share your http request for Authorization Code. It's always a bad idea to copy the code manually, because you might miss some chars or copy extra chars. It's better to programmatically grab the code from your redirect URI.

Comment: @JackZeng `https://login.windows.net/[snipped ad tenant].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=openid+offline_access&p=b2c_1_sign-in&state=[userid snipped]&client_id=[client id snipped]&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a3978%2fapi%2f2c1c7fa3%2OAuthCallback` this takes me to the login where I can login and it correctly takes me to the `/api/OAuthCallback` where I attempt to get a Token with the provided `authorization_code` and fails. I have also programmatically grabbed the code using `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` method but same error.

Comment: Your redirect URI is inconsistent. In your code request, you use `http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a3978%2fapi%2f2c1c7fa3%2OAuthCallb‌​ack`, while in your token request, you use `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3978%2Fapi%2FOAuthCallback`. It's really a bad idea to do URL escape by hand.

Comment: what would you use to do this programmatically

Comment: @JackZeng actually I made an error with that while copying pasting. This is the actual GET request to get the authorization_code: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/baad.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=openid+offline_access&p=b2c_1_sign-in&state=[state snipped]&client_id=[clientid snipped]&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a3978%2fapi%2fOAuthCallback`

Comment: @JackZeng but now I realize it redirects me to a whole different url with whole different client id!!!! I don't understand why it is redirecting to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/baad.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[totally different client id from previous request]&redirect_uri=https:%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%2fbaad.onmicrosoft.com%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=id_token&scope=email+openid&response_mode=query&nonce=BgjdgjeojEr%2fbdfgdfgdfgEQ%3d%3d&nux=1&nca=1&domain_hint=baad.onmicrosoft.com&mkt=en-US&lc=1033&prompt=login&state=ghakjdf9873jf`

Comment: @JackZeng I have asked a new question concerning this, I suspect that this is what is causing the token to be invalid, the original GET request redirects to a completely different URL with other parameters I didn't specify automatically generated... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066174/azure-ad-b2c-attempting-to-get-authorization-token-redirects-to-an-unfamiliar-l

Comment: I can't find your question, have you finally solved your problem?